# Monero GUI privacy info

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, privacy

1. If i install GUI in advanced mode with local node, when i import seed , can anyone see which wallet is being opened besides me?
2. if I open GUI wallet in simple mode and use remote node with imported seed, can anyone see which wallet is being opened?

Given - no transactions are being made, just balances check

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. No. Unless they have some kind of access to your local machine of course.
2. No.

The issue main issue with using a remote node is the operator can log (and associate), your IP address to your transaction(s). That and you're trusting they serve up valid blockchain data.